# ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7 (onDeSelect) not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get the ID of an item that was deselected but the (onDeSelect) doesn't work in ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7:
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/672hP.png)
This is the method I'm trying to use

Comment: can you post your view (html) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the OnSelectAll is called when you select an option, you need to create onItemDeSelect function in your typescript file

and use this HTML :

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7 [placeholder]="'custom placeholder' [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"> </ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7>
```

[LIVE VERSION](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

In HTML

```
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown class=""
          placeholder="Select value" 
          [data]="dropdownData"
          [settings]="dropdownSettings"
          (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
          (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
          (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
          (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
      </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

then in xxx.component.ts file

```
onDeSelectAll(items: any){
    //here you have access to all items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Event in the Component like this

```
  onItemDeSelect(item: any) {
    console.log('onItemDeSelect', item);
  }
```

and use onDeSelect on the View like this

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7 ... (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"></ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7>
```